# How to automatically re-enable a custom active job marked as "not supported" since a "Timeout while executing a shell script" in zabbix?

Tags: timeout, zabbix

I´m using zabbix to monitor some servers and I have implemented some custom functions.

the problem in this particular one is that in case of a connection error (which I'm facing), the zabbix item will be marked as "Not Supported" by the Host, and won't be executed for like 10 minutes.

I don't have an issue with the fact of the script returning no data, but I do need it to be executed every minute.

Is there a configuration I can tweak on zabbix to overcome this? I would prefer something global instead of going template by template, item by item, adding a shell timeout to each function.

I would also like to avoid solving this by adding more time to the timeout configuration, the goal is for zabbix to execute the functions again when they are meant to be executed instead of avoiding the timeout.

The agent's version is `zabbix_agentd (daemon) (Zabbix) 4.0.17`

An example of custom function is this

```
UserParameter=agent.CheckIP[*],fping $1 | grep -c alive
```

Checking the log file, I got this

```
   569:20220628:123534.628 Failed to execute command "fping 192.168.xxx.xxx | grep -c alive": Timeout while executing a shell script.
   569:20220628:123534.628 active check "ioagent.CheckIP[192.168.xxx.xxx]" is not supported: Timeout while executing a shell script.
   569:20220628:124731.420 Failed to execute command "fping 192.168.xxx.xxx | grep -c alive": Timeout while executing a shell script.
   569:20220628:124731.420 active check "ioagent.CheckIP[192.168.xxx.xxx]" is not supported: Timeout while executing a shell script.
```

Comment: Do not use `system.run["fping ..."]`: you can use buildt-in key `net.tcp.service[service,<ip>,<port>]`. Do not use `system.run[]` unless for tests.

Comment: thanks @IronBishop for your comment. I'll check net.tcp.service